# "No such file or directory" when trying to run a newly created app

Tags: trigger.io

I just discovered forge and wanted to try it out at once. I closely followed the tutorial at http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/getting-started.html#mac-and-linux-users and everything went fine, until I tried to actually run my app:

```
(forge-environment) forge run web
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.2
[   INFO] Checking JavaScript files...
[   INFO] JavaScript check complete
[   INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
[   INFO] Configuration settings check complete
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/mononofu/Programmieren/ArmorCalc/.template/generate_dynamic/utils.py", line     163, in runner
    state.proc = lib.PopenWithoutNewConsole(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=kw.get('env'))
  File "/home/mononofu/Programmieren/ArmorCalc/.template/generate_dynamic/lib.py", line 155,     in __init__
     self._old_popen.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

(it doesn't actually crash, just hangs for a while, then quits with status 131)
This happens no matter how I try to run it (android, web). I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, everything updated. I didn't change anything from the defaults, just `create` and then `build`

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you re-run the failing command with the --verbose flag and either update your question with that, or get in touch with support@trigger.io?

Comment: there is not much of a difference with `--verbose` - I guess I'll have to contact support.

Comment: @JamesBrady is a member of trigger.io team !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying error was `adb` not being found to interact with the emulator / device: we've fixed the poor error message here so that other Linux users won't be stuck in the same way!